# converting integer to set Python

Tags: python, set

I have this code

```
K = int(input())
allgroup = set([int(x) for x in input().split()])
print(list((element for element in allgroup if element not in (allgroup - set(element)))))
```

and i get this error since element is not set

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can I convert int to set?

Comment: Can you provide example usage? What is your expected input/output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the integer a collection object first.

```
print(list((element for element in allgroup if element not in (allgroup - set([element])))))
```

In the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) you can see that `set` takes an iterable as an argument.

You can alternatively make it a set directly. Thank you @TigerhawkT3.

Comment: Why `set([element])` rather than `{element}`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I added an edit

Comment: I know that the `set` function handles any iterable. I'm asking why you took the trouble to do that rather than just using a literal.

Comment: Ok, edited again.